# JDBC connection fails, when trying to login the first time, after a while

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a web application using Spring and Hibernate and mysql database.
The issue is that, when the application is up for a while and there is no activity for a long time and then if the user tries to log in, it gives the
the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1596)
org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
com.smallworks.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.getUserByLoginID(UserDAOImpl.java:102)
com.smallworks.authenticationService.impl.UserAuthenticationServiceImpl.isPasswordCorrect(UserAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:54)
com.smallworks.validation.UserLoginValidator.validate(UserLoginValidator.java:59)
com.smallworks.controller.ProjectController.signIn(ProjectController.java:84)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,781,083 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 33,781,083 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3348)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1967)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2273)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697
```

And ones the user tries to login in again, it works fine.

Following is the configuration of my Hibernate:

```
<beans>   

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/smallworks/model/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/smallworks/model/Contact.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/smallworks/model/Action.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/smallworks/model/Comment.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
             <!--  -->   
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

applicationContext.xml

```
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                 <!--  -->   
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <!-- Managing connection -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

I have edited my hibernate configuration with the above configuration, but still it does not seem to take affect.
Any guidance in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This is a timeout from your database, every connection without activity after a certain period are dropped. You can implement a connection pool manager like C3P0 :

This is a sample configuration, may be adapted to meet yours :

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
```

And you only have to add the jar from [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this, but I am not sure if I am doing it at the correct place. I have edited my question with my configuration file. Any idea what I am doing wrong?